# check in array if email exists and add one key with email and value using javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hi i am go for the generate excel file using array.and i am getting success for generate excel file. but here i  have one array and in the array i have 3 object. now in my object one key as **biography** and with value any contain store here.but i want check in the contain email id is exist than i want to new key as email and with email key value email id. for ex => biography : "hello abc@gmail.com". so here email id is avilable so i want new key email and value as a abc#gmail.com

Here my cuurent array =>

```
   var Result=> [ [ { fullName: 'abc',
                  username: 'abc',
                  biography: 'hello everyone!  abc@gmail.com',      
                  followerCount: 388,
                  followingCount: 3009,
                  mediaCount: 12 },
                { fullName: 'xyz',
                  username: 'xyz',
                  biography: 'xyz@yamil.com',      
                  followerCount: 919,
                  followingCount: 244,
                  mediaCount: 3 },
                { fullName: 'a',
                  username: 'a',
                  biography: 'I would love to change a@gmail.com',      
                  followerCount: 467,
                  followingCount: 2658,
                  mediaCount: 1 } ] ]
```

my expected array =>

```
Result=> [ [ { fullName: 'abc',
                  username: 'abc',
                  biography: 'hello everyone!  abc@gmail.com',      
                  followerCount: 388,
                  followingCount: 3009,
                  mediaCount: 12,
                  **Email : 'abc@gmail.com'** },
                { fullName: 'xyz',
                  username: 'xyz',
                  biography: 'xyz@yamil.com',      
                  followerCount: 919,
                  followingCount: 244,
                  mediaCount: 3,
                  **Email : 'xyz@yamil.com'** },
                { fullName: 'a',
                  username: 'a',
                  biography: 'I would love to change a@gmail.com',      
                  followerCount: 467,
                  followingCount: 2658,
                  mediaCount: 1,
                  **Email : 'a@gmail.com'** } ] ]
```

i want new key with email and value as a email id who store have. so any one know how can do that than please let me know. and i am take in the last used array like Result[0].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regex to find e-mails in the biography property and extract it.

```js
var Result = [
  [{
      fullName: 'abc',
      username: 'abc',
      biography: 'hello everyone!  abc@gmail.com',
      followerCount: 388,
      followingCount: 3009,
      mediaCount: 12
    },
    {
      fullName: 'xyz',
      username: 'xyz',
      biography: 'xyz@yamil.com',
      followerCount: 919,
      followingCount: 244,
      mediaCount: 3
    },
    {
      fullName: 'a',
      username: 'a',
      biography: 'I would love to change ',
      followerCount: 467,
      followingCount: 2658,
      mediaCount: 1
    }
  ]
];

Result[0].forEach(function(item) {
  var result = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/.exec(item.biography);

  item.Email = result ? result[0] : '';
});

console.log(Result);
```

Comment: Hi suppose in first object in the email id not available than i need blank Email : '' like in the first object so how can do?

Comment: Hi i am remove email id from the 3rd object and after i am run this solution i am getting error like this "Cannot read property '0' of null" so can  you please help me how can i fix.

Comment: i have remove one email id from the any object then i am getting error like this also "Cannot read property '0' of null" so how can i fix it

Comment: @Edit Should be fixed now. Please try the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response and help me